# finally для потока

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть ли что-то типа finally, только не для блока, а для потока? Так, что бы в любом случае перед закрытием потока выполнялось какое-то действие.

Answer (score 5):

Что мешает его добавить?! В методе `Run()` сделать конструкцию вида `try {} finally {}`.